# How to open Resolution Center for an app version rejection after the app is approved?

Tags: ipad, applications, resolution, app-store-connect

Something very strange happened to me. My company application was rejected in first place because App Review Team reported that it crashed in iPad Air 2. We bought a new iPad Air 2 and I faced no issues there.. However I did some small fixes here and there and uploaded a new bundle of the app. Even in this case the app was rejected with the same excuse. I had a long conversation in the Resolution Center with the App Review Team with me explaining that the app never crashed even with the new device we bought. As last thing I requested to have a video/screenrecord of the crashing moment.. After some hours surprisingly I got the application approved and ready for sale. My problem now is that I can't access the resolution center anymore. I need to have this conversation documented because my chiefs have it hard to believe that the application was accepted just at surprise :) Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found this floating around on Reddit.  I've also had the same issue and was able to find the Resolution Center from this:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/[your-app-id]/platform/ios/resolutioncenter

Update it with your AppID.  This ID is for iTC, not the bundle_id from the developer portal.  You can find it in iTC and it will be a series of numbers.

**UPDATE**

Since iTunes Connect has become App Store Connect, due to redirects, the above URL no longer works. Please use the following:

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/[your-app-id]/platform/ios/resolutioncenter

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't work anymore at that company and I don't remember the app-id to check it however I am marking your response as the correct one.

Comment: The new link above works but after a while the data will be scrubbed / blank unfortunately

Comment: For anyone trying to find the same the same data for macOS, replace `ios` in the URL with `osx`.